# Static Resources not found by Customer Community Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, customer-community, static-resources

Static resources aren't loading when my Lightning Component is hosted on a Customer Community page. They do load in-app, so I'm guessing there's a namespace issue with my resource paths when I use the component in Community.

On page load the following resources fail to load in the **live** community site, whose url is *https://mycarexchange-developer-edition.na53.force.com/s/*, but **do load** in-app as well as in Community Builder Preview.

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Leaflet +'/leaflet.css'}" 
              scripts="{!$Resource.Leaflet +'/leaflet-src.js'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
```

The errors were,

> Refused to apply style from 'https://mycarexchange-developer-edition.na53.force.com/resource/1534109270000/Leaflet/leaflet.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
>   VM40579:1 
>   GET https://mycarexchange-developer-edition.na53.force.com/resource/1534109270000/Leaflet/leaflet-src.js 404 (Not Found)

The Leaflet folder structure is as follows (**image** is the only folder in this zip, the rest are files)
Leaflet.zip
--leaflet.css
--leaflet.js
--leaflet.js.map
--leaflet-src.js.map
--leaflet-src.js
--images
----image files

Unfortunately I'm having this same issue with most of my static resources; I didn't include all examples for brevity, but will do so if it's helpful.

Comment: what about permissions to your static resource? set it's Cache Control to `Public`

Comment: @ItaiShmida That did the trick. Thank you. Can you submit as an answer so I can mark this question as 'answered'?

Comment: Also, I've found that quitting and reopening chrome sometimes solves this issue, especially when hosting components in communities. Seems like there's caching going on that causes sporadic issues with loading static resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the static resource `Cache Control`  as `Public`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the party, but if anyone is willing how to set this config automatically, you can do this by setting the `cacheControl` property on `*.resource-meta.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
</StaticResource>
```